# datetime as unique key in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a datetime (name:lud) variable in my database table. It registers in this format  2011-04-11 07:08:02. Now i want to make an unique key in combination with an article_id: article_id + lud.
But for the unique key lud part only 2011-04-11 07:08 is needed. 
eg lud 2011-04-11 07:08 + article_id 45

Answer (score 1):

As a variant - you could change type of the `lud` field to VARCHAR and use length option of index.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
  article_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  lud VARCHAR(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX UK_mytable (article_id, lud (16))
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES 
  (1, '2011-04-11 07:08:11');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES 
  (1, '2011-04-11 07:09:11');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES 
  (1, '2011-04-11 07:09:30');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-2011-04-11 07:09' for key 'UK_mytable'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(lud,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'),article_id)
```